# Why is the CSS Javascript dropdown menu not showing in any browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

This is the code snippet of the navigational bar I have been trying to make using HTML5, CSS and JavaScript. The **Dropdown** menu I am attempting to make using CSS and Javascript is similar to the one given as an example in the W3Schools website. This is the code snippet I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable= yes">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="description" content="FoodMeets">
<meta name="keywords" content="Restaurants, Bars, Pubs, Cafes, Nightclubs, Hangout places, Hangout zones, Chat forum, Social networking">
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow">

<!--Materialize CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/materialize.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" />

<!--Normalize CSS-->
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.1/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!--Google Icons-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />

<title>FoodMeets</title>
<style>
   html,body{
      font-family: Georgia, serif;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size: 16px;
      background-color: #eceff1;
   }
   nav{
      background-color: white;}
   nav ul a{
      color: #17479e;
       font-weight: normal;
    }
    nav ul a:hover{
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .nav-wrapper a:hover{
      color: #17479e;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .icon-design{
      position:relative;
       top: 4px;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
   .right{
        position: relative;
        left: -40px;
    }
   .dropbtn{
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .dropdown {
       display: inline-block;
     }

     .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     }

     .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
      }

     .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

     .show {display:block;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="z-depth-1">
       <div class="nav-wrapper">
          <a href="#" class="brand-logo center"><img src="images/foodmeets_logo.png" style="position:relative; width:118px; height:69px; top:-2px"/></a>
          <div class="container">
             <ul class="left">
               <li><a href="#"><span class="material-icons icon-design" aria-hidden="true">&#xE88A;</span>Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="#"><span class="material-icons icon-design" aria-hidden="true">&#xE866;</span>Featured</a></li>
               <li><a href="#"><span class="material-icons icon-design" aria-hidden="true">&#xE87D;</span>Favorites</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="right">
               <li><a href="#"><span class="material-icons icon-design">&#xE878;</span>Events & Offers</a></li>
               <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Dropdown</a>
                  <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
                     <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                     <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                     <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                  </div>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </nav>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script>
    /* When the user clicks on the button, toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
   function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }

   // Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
   window.onclick = function(event) {
   if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

       var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
       var i;
       for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
          var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
          if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
             openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
          }
        }
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the result I am getting out of this code:

[Navigational Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEeOd.png)

But the Dropdown menu does not seem to work whatever I try to do. I am using Materialize CSS here along with Google Icons.

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong or is there something wrong with my approach?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

works for me

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable= yes">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="description" content="FoodMeets">
<meta name="keywords" content="Restaurants, Bars, Pubs, Cafes, Nightclubs, Hangout places, Hangout zones, Chat forum, Social networking">
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow">

<!--Materialize CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://materializecss.com/dist/css/materialize.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" />

<!--Normalize CSS-->
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.1/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!--Google Icons-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />

<title>FoodMeets</title>
<style>
   html,body{
      font-family: Georgia, serif;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size: 16px;
      background-color: #eceff1;
   }
   nav{
      background-color: white;}
   nav ul a{
      color: #17479e;
       font-weight: normal;
    }
    nav ul a:hover{
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .nav-wrapper a:hover{
      color: #17479e;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .icon-design{
      position:relative;
       top: 4px;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
   .right{
        position: relative;
        left: -40px;
    }
   .dropbtn{
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .dropdown {
       display: inline-block;
     }

     .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     }

     .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
      }

     .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

     .show {display:block;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="z-depth-1">
       <div class="nav-wrapper">
          <a href="#" class="brand-logo center"><img src="images/foodmeets_logo.png" style="position:relative; width:118px; height:69px; top:-2px"/></a>
          <div class="container">
             <ul class="left">
               <li><a href="#"><span class="material-icons icon-design" aria-hidden="true">&#xE88A;</span>Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="#"><span class="material-icons icon-design" aria-hidden="true">&#xE866;</span>Featured</a></li>
               <li><a href="#"><span class="material-icons icon-design" aria-hidden="true">&#xE87D;</span>Favorites</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="right">
               <li><a href="#"><span class="material-icons icon-design">&#xE878;</span>Events & Offers</a></li>
               <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn"  data-activates='myDropdown'>Dropdown</a>
                  <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
                     <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                     <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                     <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                  </div>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </nav>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://materializecss.com/bin/materialize.js"></script>
<script>
    /* When the user clicks on the button, toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
/*   function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }

   // Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
   window.onclick = function(event) {
   if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

       var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
       var i;
       for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
          var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
          if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
             openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
          }
        }
    }
}*/

$('.dropbtn').dropdown({
      inDuration: 300,
      outDuration: 225,
      constrain_width: false, // Does not change width of dropdown to that of the activator
      hover: true, // Activate on hover
      gutter: 0, // Spacing from edge
      belowOrigin: false, // Displays dropdown below the button
      alignment: 'left' // Displays dropdown with edge aligned to the left of button
    }
  );
     
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes this works, but can you explain why the one I did does not ? @Monzur

Comment: Yes I knew about this, but I wanted to have a dropdown menu which appears below the menu, like a traditional drop down, which can be set in your code as well by making belowOrigin: true @Monzur

Comment: add on css 
#myDropdown{
    margin-top:64px;
}

Comment: If i turn the hover:false, clicking inside the dropdown content closes it

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work - as evidence in this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/67j1sLkt/

Looks like you need to do some more debugging on your end, because this can be a number of issues. The first 2 that would come to mind are:

1. **Absolute positioning off of the screen**. You have your `.dropdown-content` set to `position: absolute`, but you have to ask yourself relative to what? I would suggest adding `position: relative;` to your `.dropdown` class
2. **z-index**. This determines the layers of elements. So it could be that the element is being shown below the background or something.

**Some debugging help** - if you are in Chrome, I would suggest right clicking on the `Dropdown` button and select `Inspect`. Now use your developer tools to highlight your `#myDropdown` and it should tell you where that element is positioned on the page (if it is shown at that point). You should also check your console for errors to see if that is what the issue is.

Comment: I tried keeping the position for dropdown class as relative and put z-depth-0 which essentially is z-index:0 but there is no change. I think a few Materialize CSS classes may be interfering with the code @Adjit

Comment: @CodeBunny have you used the debugger? Because you can see what CSS classes are being applied / taking precedence.

Answer (score -1):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
     function myFunction(){
       $(".dropbtn").click(function() {
          $("#myDropdown").toggle();
       });   
     }
```

this much is fulfill your requirement

Comment: This would change nothing.  It's fine to define `myFunction` before DOM ready.  `myFunction` needs to *run* after DOM ready, but since it's triggered by a user click, that's already guaranteed without a document.ready wrapper.